# Unable to publish data to Kafka Topic using pyflink 1.17.1

Tags: python, apache-kafka, apache-flink, pyflink

I am trying to publish the data which was originally a `list` but I converted it to the `string` and then tried to push it to the `Kafka` topic as per this [official documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/connectors/datastream/kafka/#kafka-sink) I tried the below code:

```
sink = KafkaSink.builder() \
            .set_bootstrap_servers("localhost:9092") \
            .set_record_serializer(
            KafkaRecordSerializationSchema.builder()
            .set_topic("test-topic45")
            .set_value_serialization_schema(SimpleStringSchema())
            .build()
        ) \
            .build()
datastream.sink_to(sink)
```

but it threw the below error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class [B cannot be cast to class java.lang.String ([B and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

I even tried setting up the `key` serializer to `SimpleStringSchema`(which I don't think was needed) but same result.

Also, I don't need to convert explicitly since `SimpleStringSchema` will handle it for me also I have ensured my upstream layers are working fine. Absolutely no problem with that.

The upstream layer to this is the `process function` which returns a `list of tuples of tuples` and I haven't mentioned the `output_type` parameter for the `process function`. Should I mention it or will it be handled by `SimpleStringSchema`?

Is there anything else I am missing here?

Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're right. The error indicates the stream record doesn't match to what's been specified in the Kafka sink builder.

You would find JSON to be more useful than STRING and the Flink document has an example about how to serialise Kafka key and value with JSON - see [link](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/connectors/datastream/formats/json/#python)

Below shows a quick working example. Note you should have the connector JAR file in (`./jars/flink-sql-connector-kafka-1.17.1.jar`).

```py
import os

from pyflink.common import Row
from pyflink.common.typeinfo import Types
from pyflink.datastream import StreamExecutionEnvironment, RuntimeExecutionMode, TimeCharacteristic
from pyflink.datastream.connectors.kafka import (
    KafkaSink,
    KafkaRecordSerializationSchema,
    DeliveryGuarantee,
)
from pyflink.datastream.formats.json import JsonRowSerializationSchema

BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS = os.getenv("BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS", "localhost:29092")

env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
env.set_runtime_mode(RuntimeExecutionMode.STREAMING)
env.set_stream_time_characteristic(TimeCharacteristic.ProcessingTime)
SRC_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
jar_files = ["flink-sql-connector-kafka-1.17.1.jar"]
jar_paths = tuple([f"file://{os.path.join(SRC_DIR, 'jars', name)}" for name in jar_files])
print(jar_paths)
env.add_jars(*jar_paths)

value_type_info = Types.ROW_NAMED(
    field_names=["data"],
    field_types=[Types.STRING()],
)

source_stream = env.from_collection(
    collection=[
        [
            (("user1", "gold"), ("user2", "gold"), ("user5", "gold")),
            (("user3", "gold"), ("user4", "gold"), ("user6", "gold")),
        ]
    ]
)


sink = (
    KafkaSink.builder()
    .set_bootstrap_servers(BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS)
    .set_record_serializer(
        KafkaRecordSerializationSchema.builder()
        .set_topic("sink-demo")
        .set_value_serialization_schema(
            JsonRowSerializationSchema.builder().with_type_info(value_type_info).build()
        )
        .build()
    )
    .set_delivery_guarantee(DeliveryGuarantee.AT_LEAST_ONCE)
    .build()
)

# source_stream.map(lambda e: Row(data=str(e)), output_type=value_type_info).print()
source_stream.map(lambda e: Row(data=str(e)), output_type=value_type_info).sink_to(sink).name(
    "sink-demo"
).uid("sink-demo")

env.execute("Kafka sink example.")
```

If successful, you should be able see the following Kafka message.

[image]

Also the message value can be parsed as shown below. Note it only works with Python and wouldn't be recommended if the messages are shared by other data types.

[image]

Comment: Okay but in my case since I am getting data in this format `[(('user1', 'gold'), ('user2', 'gold'), ('user5', 'gold')), (('user3', 'gold'), ('user4', 'gold'), ('user6', 'gold'))] `, I tried putting the value for `output_type` of process function as `Types.LIST(Types.TUPLE([Types.STRING(), Types.STRING(), Types.STRING()]) ` so is there any need to do anything else?

Comment: Or should I remove the output_type from the process function and just use `map` and put this output_type there? @JaehyeonKim

Comment: For me, it'd be easier to convert it into string. Later we can parse it without a problem. I updated my answer with your example data.

Comment: Yeah, it worked but I am just curious this time can I do some manipulation to get the data in the form of a `List of Tuple of Tuples`? Right now it is in the form of `List of List of List`. I want to retain my original form. How can I do that? or is it practically not possible? @JaehyeonKim

Comment: I tried changing the `Types.ROW_NAMED` to `Types.TUPLE`(which is another available static method) but it threw an error saying that only `RowTypeInfo` is supported. So, I wasn't able to return `TupleTypeInfo`

Comment: I updated my answer with an option to preserve the original data structure. Note it'll only work with Python.

Comment: Okay, so this change was simple @JaehyeonKim. I was actually trying to change the Java type here but thanks you made my day once again :)